# I am having trouble with this css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am tying to make a modal and I am having hard time making tools and close button appear on the same line. It should be like the below image:

[image]

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.61);
}

.cButton {
  position: realtive;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBtn">Open Modal</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div id="closeButton" class="cButton">
      <p>tools</p>
      <div class="close">&times;</div>
    </div>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

And also I want the top  of the modal box to have the style like in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Try to use `span` instead of `div` like this: `<p>tools<span class="close">&times;</span></p>`

Comment: Make the text and the closing buttons inline elements and give them a `vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: You also correct the typo `.cButton { position: >>realtive;<<` to `"relative"`.

Comment: it works... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `display:flex` to the `.cButton` class

```
.cButton {
  /*rest of code*/
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

You can also delete the `position:absolute` from the `.close` class.

For the triangle, you can use [`border-left, border-right, border-bottom`](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) to create it.

Check the snippet for example

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.61);
}

.cButton {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.cButton:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  right: 25px;
  top: -15px;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #000;
}

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBtn">Open Modal</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div id="closeButton" class="cButton">
      <p>tools</p>
      <div class="close">&times;</div>
    </div>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a quick try.

The close button was already positioned absolute, but without `tob/bottom/left/right` values. you also had a typo in the `cButton` class: `position: realtive;`.

The triangle at the top is made with the `before` and `after` element of the modal container using css triangle shapes (see https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/). I also offsettet the modal down a bit to leave space for the triangle and placed it on click position ;)

You can place the modal using the  `tob/bottom/left/right` css attributes and adjust the offset with the `transform` attribute of the modal.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function(e) {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modal.style.top = e.clientY+'px';
  modal.style.left = e.clientX+'px';
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(12px);
}

.modal::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 17px solid transparent;
  border-right: 17px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 12px solid #55f;
  position: absolute;
  top: -11px;
  left: 0;
}
.modal::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 2px;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.61);
}

.cButton {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 17px;
  right:4px;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBtn">Open Modal</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div id="closeButton" class="cButton">
      <p>tools</p>
      <div class="close">&times;</div>
    </div>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet below I removed the position absolute since you wont need that. It works perfectly as an inline. The problem here was that your `p` tag was a block element so I made that inline by adding a class to it and styling it. See snippet below.

It is also an idea to remove the `p` out of the closing button since I'm not sure if you want it to be part of it.

Good luck.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.61);
}

.cButton {
  position: realtive;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.close {
  /*position: absolute; <-Remove this-->*/
  display: inline;
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p.boxtitle {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBtn">Open Modal</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div id="closeButton" class="cButton">
      <p class="boxtitle">tools</p>
      <div class="close">&times;</div>
    </div>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.61);
}

.cButton {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  width: 100px;
  border-top: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-indent:5px;
}

.close {
      position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 13px;
    right: 8px;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Just Replace the css u will get expected Result